# Using Elasticsearch + Logstash to push aggregated statistics to Kafka

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, apache-kafka

We're playing with Kafka, Elasticsearch and Logstash. For the sake of experimentation, we would like to build a small service that:

1. Produce "click" messages when a user click on a given link, and push them to Kafka
2. Index those click messages into Elasticsearch
3. Aggregate those click messages and push them to Kafka.

At this point we've got the service that produce click messages and push them into a Kafka topic, and we're using Logstash to read these messages and push them into Elasticsearch.

What we need now is a way to produce new Kafka messages containing aggregated results. We tried using the following Logstash configuration file (the aggregation request is totally random at this point):

```
input {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost"
        query => '{
                      "query": {
                        "query_string": {
                          "query": "*",
                          "analyze_wildcard": true
                        }
                      },
                      "size": 0,
                      "aggs": {
                          "messages": {
                              "value_count": {
                                  "field": "message"
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }'
    }
}
output {
    kafka {
        topic_id => 'aggregated_stats'
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, Elasticsearch gives us the following error message:

```
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException: aggregations are not supported with search_type=scan
```

Moreover, it seems like Logstash immediately exits after having produced a single message, while we would like it to continuously produce new messages as the aggregated statistics change.

**Does any of this make sense?**

Answer (score 0):

It's working on my server when adding "broker_list" in the output confuguration.

```
output {
      kafka {
      broker_list => "x.x.x.x:9092,y.y.y.y:9092"
      topic_id => "aggregated_stats"
      }
}
```

Comment: Adding the broker list doesn't change anything for me, it was already finding the brokers before. Which version of Elasticsearch, Kafka and Logstash are you using?

Comment: logstash 1.5.4
kafka 0.8.2.1-1
elasticsearch 1.7.x

A scenario i've tested is different from your: Logstash(producer) --> kafka <-- Logstash(consumer).

Comment: #logstash_config (PRODUCER)
input {
  # json
  heartbeat {
    interval => 5
    # Change the "A" to another letter on the other servers
    message  => "Ingestion ZOOKEEPER-1 heartbeat"
  }
}

filter {

}

output {
  if "metric_message" not in [tags] {
      kafka {
      broker_list => "x.x.x.x:9092,y.y.y.y:9092"
      topic_id => "demo"
      client_id => 01
      request_required_acks => 1
      }
  }
}

Comment: #logstash_config (CONSUMER)
input {
  kafka {
    zk_connect                          => "a.a.a.a:2181,b.b.b.b:2181"
    group_id                              => "demo"
    topic_id                              => "demo"
    reset_beginning                  => false
    consumer_threads              => 4
    consumer_restart_on_error  => true
    consumer_restart_sleep_ms => 100
    decorate_events                  => true
  }
}

filter {

}
output {

    elasticsearch {
      host                => ["x.x.x.x:9200","y.y.y.y:9200"]
      #other configuration          
    }
}